# Recruiter pay model

Tags: job-search, recruitment

Recently I've been dealing with a lot of recruiters.

I've noticed a lot of odd behaviour such as one recruiter trying to get me to apply for a position not well suited to me, other recruiters contacting me without having properly looked through my CV recruiters and sending emails of senior roles instead of junior ones.

This raises the question what exactly are recruiters getting paid by their clients to do. Are they paid for each vaguely suitable person who applies, paid per interview or paid only for filling a position?

It has been suggested that recruits may be attempting to stuff roles with bad applicants to make good applicants seem better, is this something that happens a lot?

It would be interesting to get a recruiters perspective on this.

Answer (score -1):

> Are they paid for each vaguely suitable person who applies, paid per interview or paid only for filling a position?

It's fair to say that there may be different models in different regions or industries, but every recruiter I've ever worked with has been paid a commission based on the position's salary, once they have provided a candidate who accepts and fills the role.

In a shortsighted way, they are incented to provide a high volume of candidates in order to "spam" and hope that one sticks. However, recruiters with good strategy understand that employers will be more likely to work with them in the future if they carefully screen candidates and have a track record of providing high quality people. Some recruiters certainly use the tactics you're describing but it isn't universal and arguably isn't good for their long term success.

Answer (score -1):

The answers to this will depend a lot on the country/region, and sometimes on the specific market/vertical. Having said that, for the tech market in London (UK) I'd say this:

> This raises the question what exactly are recruiters getting paid by their clients to do. Are they paid for each vaguely suitable person who applies, paid per interview or paid only for filling a position?

In the vast majority of cases they are only paid when the position is filled - and the candidate stays in the company for a certain amount of time (e.g. 6 months).

> It has been suggested that recruits may be attempting to stuff roles with bad applicants to make good applicants seem better, is this something that happens a lot?

Sometimes is more like they deal with hard to fill positions - due to lack of sufficiently qualified applicants - so they just try with as many people as they can.

Keep in mind that (at least here in the UK) the typical recruiter fee starts at around 20%-25% of the yearly salary of the position filled - which is a lot of money. So, it is not that surprising to see some recruiters trying these kind of spammy approaches (specially the most inexperienced ones).

Comment: it's really closer to 12